# Hiding UIView after Network Notification

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using the following code to detect when a user has connectivity to the internet. If there's no connectivity, add a subview to show that. If the user regains connectivity, remove the view.

Adding the view works just fine, however removing it isn't working. Anybody know why? (Yes, I have double checked that removeNetworkIndicator is getting called)

```
- (void)testInternetConnection
{
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

    internetReachable = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"google.com"];

    // Internet is reachable
    internetReachable.reachableBlock = ^(Reachability*reach)
    {
        // Update the UI on the main thread
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [weakSelf removeNetworkIndicator];
        });
    };

    // Internet is not reachable
    internetReachable.unreachableBlock = ^(Reachability*reach)
    {
        // Update the UI on the main thread
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [weakSelf addNetworkIndicator];
        });
    };

    [internetReachable startNotifier];
}

- (void)addNetworkIndicator {
    NetworkIndicatorViewController *networkIndicatorView = [[NetworkIndicatorViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NetworkIndicatorViewController" bundle:nil]; //creat an instance of your custom view
    networkIndicatorView.activityIndicator.hidden = YES;
    networkIndicatorView.view.tag = 400;
    [self.view addSubview:networkIndicatorView.view];
}

- (void)removeNetworkIndicator {
    UIView *networkIndicator = (UIView *)[self.view viewWithTag:400];
    NSLog(@"networkindicator: %@",networkIndicator);
    networkIndicator.hidden = YES;
    [networkIndicator removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Sidenote: the NSLog networkindicator is logging (null) but I don't understand why...

Comment: If `[self.view viewWithTag:400]` is returning nil, it means it can't find a view with that tag in self.view.  One thing that seems suspect is that your NetworkIndicatorViewController is going to be dealloc'd when it goes out of scope.  I wonder if it's doing something to the view when that happens.  You might try creating a strong property in your class to keep a reference on it so it doesn't go away.  Also, make sure in your NetworkIndicatorViewController.xib file you're not re-defining the tag to something besides 400.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not immediately clear to me why your current code isn't working, but in the meantime, you can do this:

```
- (void)removeNetworkIndicator {
    for(UIView *subview in self.view.subviews) {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[NetworkIndicatorViewController class]]) {
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
}
```

---

Also... make sure you're using a `UIView` subclass and not a `UIViewController` subclass.

Comment: it's weird, I tried this already and it didn't work either. I have no idea why this is happening...

Comment: Is `NetworkIndicatorViewController` a subclass of `UIView` or `UIViewController`?

Comment: This is probably part of the problem... view CONTROLLERS shouldn't be added as subviews...

Comment: quick question actually: if I create a new xib and subclass it as part of UIView, xcode won't automatically generate a .h/.m to handle custom initialization. Do I create these files manually?

Answer (score 0):

create a property for the view in your view controller:

`@property (nonatomic, strong) NetworkIndicatorViewController *networkIndicatorView`

and then simply use this to show:

`[self.view addSubview:self.networkIndicatorView.view];`

and this to hide:

`[self.networkIndicatorView.view removeFromSuperview];`